# (Python)ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, import, importerror

I have a variable named nombre in file 1.

```
print("\nREGISTRO DE USUARIO\n")
nombre=input("Nombre completo: ")
tel=input("Numero telefonico: ")
direc=input("Direccion: ")
print("\t\tUSUARIO REGISTRADO")
input()
```

Now, I want to import the variable nombre to file 2

```
    from usuario import nombre
    numerolista=[]
    numerolista.append(nombre)
    print (numerolista)
```

But it returns the error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'nombre'.

Comment: Is that the full code? It should work

Comment: files should be in same folder

Comment: They must be in the same folder, because otherwise it would throw an error can't find the module `usuario` before it would say it can't import name `nombre`

Comment: Yes codes're working.Check the directories and try again

Comment: May be `usuario` is not the file where you have your `input()` related code.  Why don't you tell us the real file names instead of saying 'file1' and 'file2'

Comment: First of all, thanks to everyone who has commented. File 1 real name is usuario.py and file 2 name is listausu.py They are both inside the same folder "biblioteca". I'm using pythonanywhere, maybe there's an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check weather the files were there in the same folder. in case they were there in different folder try adding the folder path which is having the first file in your import section. You can add the path in the following way.

```
    from sys import path
    path += [<first_file_path>]
```

and remember while adding path just specify the folder path, for instance if the first file is in 
        D:\Data\Python\Work\file1.py

specify the path as

```
    path += ['D:\\Data\\Python\\Work']
```

if you have the second file also in the same hierarchy you can specify the path as below. Lets Say your second file is in the following path

```
    D:\Data\Python\files\file2.py
```

In thi scase you can specify the path as

```
    path += ['..\\Work']
```

Dont forget to add these 2 lines before your **from usuario import nombre**. So that first the path will be added the library path so that your import statement will work.

Hope this will help you.
Thanks